# Will a standard_layout class's data member have a fixed offset from the object's address?

Tags: c++, type-traits, offsetof, object-layout

If a class [is_standard_layout](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_standard_layout/), is that sufficient to guarantee that a given non-static data member will always have the same offset from the object's address (i.e. same across different instances of that class, process-wide)?

Comment: I think it is also depends on word size and alignment.

Comment: @ZangMingJie I meant only a process-wide guarantee. Will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That effectively has to hold for objects of any type (within a program). Accessing a subobject happens via offsets which are known at compile-time and constant in machine code. For SL types, you can verify this via `offsetof` - which is guaranteed to work for standard-layout types and basically implies a uniform offset.

Comment: It says [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/) that `offsetof` requires a POD class, which is a stronger requirement than standard_layout. That is why I came here to ask.

Comment: @tennenrishin Check the C++11 tab.

Comment: Oh a browser plugin was preventing it from rendering the tabs so it was listing all the requirements from all the standards! That really unconfused my day for me. Thanks.